# Nest can't resolve dependency of UserService during testing

Tags: mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to write a unit test for the `UserService` which has Mongoose model as a dependency but when I run the tests it can't be resolved.

**user.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DatabaseModule } from '../database/database.module';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import userProviders from './providers';

@Module({
  imports: [DatabaseModule],
  providers: [UserService, ...userProviders],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**user.provider.ts**

```
import { Connection } from 'mongoose';

import { UserSchema } from '../schemas/user.schema';
import { USER_MODEL_PROVIDER, DB_PROVIDER } from '../../../constants/database';
import { Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
import { USER_MODEL } from '../../../constants/models';

export const userProvider: Provider = {
  provide: USER_MODEL_PROVIDER,
  useFactory: (connection: Connection) =>
    connection.model(USER_MODEL, UserSchema),
  inject: [DB_PROVIDER],
};
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from './interfaces/user.interface';
import { USER_MODEL } from '../../constants/models';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { UpdateUserDto } from './dto/update-user.dto';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(USER_MODEL)
    private readonly userModel: Model<User>,
  ) {}

  async getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.userModel.find().exec();
  }

  async getUser(userId: any): Promise<User> {
    return this.userModel.findById(userId).exec();
  }

  async addUser(dto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    return new this.userModel(dto).save();
  }

  async updateUser(userId: any, dto: UpdateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    return this.userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, dto, {
      new: true,
    });
  }
}
```

**user.service.spec.ts**

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { USER_MODEL } from '../../constants/models';
import { User } from './interfaces/user.interface';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import userProviders from './providers';
import { DatabaseModule } from '../database/database.module';

describe('UserService', () => {
  let userService: UserService;
  let userModel: Model<User>;
  const token = getModelToken(USER_MODEL);

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const userModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [DatabaseModule],
      providers: [UserService, ...userProviders],
    }).compile();

    userService = userModule.get<UserService>(UserService);
    userModel = userModule.get(token);
  });

  it('should get all users', async () => {
    const users = await userService.getUsers();
    expect(users).toEqual([]);
  });
});
```

How can I inject the model so it would be available during the testing phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved; `USER_MODEL_PROVIDER` contained different value than `USER_MODEL` so `UserSchema` was never even injected.